# Xcode - Swift - UILabel in TableViewCell Expansion

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I have a UILabel in a custom UITableViewCell called "ScheduleCell", like so:

[image]

Here is the code for ScheduleCell:

```
import UIKit

class ScheduleCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

I want the tileLabel to expand based on its text and I want the ScheduleCell to expand with it. Here are the attributes of the titleLabel:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here are the attributes of the cell prototype, which is linked to the ScheduleCell class:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is some relevant code for the ViewController:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160.0
```

And

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!,cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! ScheduleCell

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xF6FBFE)

    cell.titleLabel.text = (Globals.scheduleArr[indexPath.row][3] as! String)
    cell.titleLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    return cell
}
```

All of the titles from "Globals.scheduleArr" fit on one line except one, which is "Jane Richards Grey Reads "To Kill a Mockingbird"". Here is what the ViewController looks like in the iOS Simulator:

[image]

As you can see, the label does not expand as necessary. Strangely enough, when I add a "\n" to the end of each of the titles, the label does expand. However, the cell doesn't seem to expand with the label:

[image]

Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use UITableViewAutomaticDimension, you need to add Label-ContentView **bottom constraint**.

Add new bottom constraint and try again!